# Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded

Tags: linux, vps, wine

I'm trying to open .exe file on my Linux vps, yet when i try i get this error:

```
hitleap@STEFAN:~/Desktop$ wine Hitleap+Viewer.exe
it looks like multiarch needs to be enabled.  as root, please
execute "dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get install wine32"
wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\home\hitleap\Desktop\HitLeap+Viewer.exe.
hitleap@STEFAN:~/Desktop$ Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that #DISPLAY is set correctly.
```

How to make this work?

Comment: This was Q&A question, i've posted answer below.

Answer (score 3):

As per your message:

> It looks like multiarch needs to be enabled. As root, please
>   execute "`dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get install wine32`"

So as root, type the following command and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get install wine32
```

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 14.04, this was solved by installing 32 bit version of libSM6:

```
sudo apt-get install libsm6:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

As silly as it sounds. Switch off and on my laptop was what worked for me :)